# eBay Analytics API - Invalid Auth

Tags: php, curl, ebay-api

I've logged into eBay and generated an Auth'n'Auth access token:

[image: eBay Screenshot]

I've then used this token in the following request:

```
$headers = array (
  'Authorization: Bearer ' . $auth_token
);

$url = "https://api.ebay.com/sell/analytics/v1/traffic_report?dimension=DAY&filter=marketplace_ids:{EBAY_GB},date_range:[20160814..20160824]&metric=LISTING_IMPRESSION_SEARCH_RESULTS_PAGE,LISTING_IMPRESSION_STORE";

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

However I get the following response:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [errorId] => 1001
                    [domain] => OAuth
                    [category] => REQUEST
                    [message] => Invalid access token
                    [longMessage] => Invalid access token. Check the value of the Authorization HTTP request header.
                )

        )

)
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getTrafficReport requires a oAuth token and not an Auth'n'Auth one - https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/analytics/resources/traffic_report/methods/getTrafficReport

Comment: @Lee No worries! It happens to all of us. Good luck!